# Why is Bone Transformation Constraint Speed too high?

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

link to a video of my problem : https://youtu.be/EI8dHZs6VF0

I have a problem from my rig. Apart from my IK I have made some bone constraint transformation mapped to the relative position of the leading IK hands local position.

Although I have made correct input of the ranges of the transformation map, I get extra quick transformations from my connected bones and not a uniform change along the maps range of values

For example my front shoulders "bone" is set to rotate around local Y for a range of local Y values of the IK hand. Although the range is big the transformation happens instantly.

I though of the projects units BU so I went ahead and changed the scale and units of the project, thinking that the transform map used increments of the projects units for the transformations steps, but i had no luck with that :/ .

Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0):

salpix here i just solved it. if anyone finds the question i just made an error in the units i placed in the ranges. double check your units and drag the window to make it bigger and the view clearer